# how to convert a json_encoded data to an associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this data.how can i convert this to a php associative array?Actually am confused.I tried with **json_decode** and **unserialize**.Anyone here to help me.thanks in advance.

```
  "data": {
    "address": "101, B Wing, Ashapura Park, Dombivli East",
    "area": "thane",
    "area_id": 51466,

    "field_agent": {
      "email": "abin@example.in",
      "name": "Jacob Mattom",
      "phone": 2147483647
    },
    "geo_location_city": "thane",
    "geo_location_city_id": 2430,
    "keywords": [
      "sample for tesing"
    ],
    "lat": null,
    "lng": null,
    "location_id": 5578,
    "media": [
      {
        "MediaId": "0bd41ec2f0bc11e58fd5066a28c33ece",
        "thumb_url": "http://example-datapipeline-staging.s3-ap-southeast-1.examplezz.com/0bd41ec2f0bc11e58fd5066a28c33ece.mp4",
      },
      {
        "MediaId": "28c3823ef0bc11e5b825066a28c33ece",
        "thumb_url": "http://example-datapipeline-staging.s3-ap-southeast-1.examplezz.com/28c3823ef0bc11e5b825066a28c33ece.mp4",
      }
    ],
    "meta": {
      "Product": [
        {
          "brand": "",
          "categorykeywords": [
            "Construction Tools Indl",
            "Construction Tools",
            "Industrial Construction Tools",
            "Tools",
            ""
          ],
          "categorykeywordsexact": [
            "Construction Tools Indl",
            "Construction Tools",
            "Industrial Construction Tools",
            "Tools",
            ""
          ],
          "categorypath": "Top/Construction Equipments/Construction Tools- Indl",
          "description": "",
          "id": 10395376,
          "imageurls": "",
          "intattribute": [
            {
              "answer": 0,
              "qaggr": "",
              "question": ""
            },
            {
              "answer": 0,
              "qaggr": "",
              "question": ""
            },
            {
              "answer": 0,
              "qaggr": "",
              "question": ""
            },
            {
              "answer": 0,
              "qaggr": "",
              "question": ""
            }
          ],
          "keywords": [],
          "l1category": "Building & Construction",
          "l2category": "Construction Equipments",
          "name": "",
          "parkedkeywords": [],
          "stringattribute": [
            {
              "aaggr": [
                "New"
              ],
              "answer": [
                "New"
              ],
              "qaggr": "Condition",
              "question": "Condition"
            },
            {
              "aaggr": [
                "Customized",
                "Warranty"
              ],
              "answer": [
                "Customized",
                "Warranty"
              ],
              "qaggr": "Services",
              "question": "Services"
            },
            {
              "aaggr": [
                "Electric",
                "Hydraulic",
                "Pneumatic"
              ],
              "answer": [
                "Electric",
                "Hydraulic",
                "Pneumatic"
              ],
              "qaggr": "Technology",
              "question": "Technology"
            },
            {
              "aaggr": [
                "Cutting Tools",
                "Hand Tools",
                "Plumbing Tools",
                "Power Tools"
              ],
              "answer": [
                "Cutting Tools",
                "Hand Tools",
                "Plumbing Tools",
                "Power Tools"
              ],
              "qaggr": "Tools",
              "question": "Tools"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "keywords1": [
        "sample for tesing"
      ],
      "project": "ace"
    },
    "outlet_status": "Valid Data",
    "outlet_type": 0,
    "phones": [
      {
        "type": "mobile",
        "value": "+9198955548554"
      },
      {
        "type": "tollfree",
        "value": ""
      }
    ],
    "pincode": "22601",
    "pincode_id": 151522,
    "products": null,
    "progress": "field executive assigned",
    "qc_agency": null,
    "qc_agent": null
  },
  "message": null,
  "status": true
}
```

I have this data.how can i convert this to a php associative array?Actually am confused.I tried with **json_decode** and **unserialize**.Anyone here to help me.thanks in advance.

Comment: What happened when you used json_decode?  Why couldn't you use that?

Comment: json_decode() is what you need. When you try this function what does it return? Also make sure you have true as the second parameter to return an associated arrays and not an objects.

Comment: Did you forgot to paste the first "{"? or is it missing?

Comment: yup bro..thank u. :)

Comment: i forgot to put that data within a single qotes.

Comment: first  your `json` is not valid so correct it and then do `<?php echo "<pre/>";print_r(json_decode(your variable here));?>`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution is to use json_decode.

```
$json= '"data": {"address": "101, B Wing, Ashapura Park, Dombivli East", "area": "thane", "area_id": 51466, "field_agent": {"email": "abin@example.in", "name": "Jacob Mattom", "phone": 2147483647 }}';

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->address;
echo $obj->field_agent->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data structure is wrong. Because of that php's json_decode doesn't work with it. First fix it. For to fix that you can use a online json editor.
What is wrong with your json data:

1. Write your data between curly braces
2. Don't use comma for last item of a list

Now you can use json_decode it is ok.

Here is the fixed version of your JSON data:
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=689de1b78324faaced8018a2ccda1845